# Excel Macro or Function to clear cell content if not a date

Tags: excel, vba

**Issue**

Garbage gets erroneously entered into date fields and screws up calculations.

**Goal**

Using a macro or function to check the contents in a range of cells, determine if they are dates and if not, delete the non-date contents.

**What I've Tried**

Using Search and Replace function to locate and delete offending items.  Takes forever and still doesn't clear everything out.

Any ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this

```
Sub DeleteNonDates()
    Dim r As Range, a As Range, cl As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    For Each cl In r.Cells
        If TypeName(cl.Value) <> "Date" Then
            cl.ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, I just had to define the range and it work beautifully.  Thanks.